# how to detect clicks count within 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count mouse clicks on anywhere of page with jQuery.

If user clicks more than 10 click within 5 second I want to give a message.

Time counter will be checked elapsed time on every last click.

I'll use this code to prevent unwanted network traffic on my site. Because, I have a calender on page; every click of calender gets too many data (event/news lists) from server. If user click too much, it may block my site.

Comment: And what did you try already?

Comment: May I ask why this question is getting downvoted?
There isnt really a reason for that.
Its a proper question, and if you do it because he didnt post his code. just ask him for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my "improved" version:

```
var tOuts = [];
$(document).click(function(){
    tOuts.push( setTimeout(function(){
        tOuts.shift();
    }, 5000) );

    if (tOuts.length == 10) {
        // clear all the timeouts
        for (x in tOuts) { clearTimeout(tOuts[x]); }
        tOuts = [];
        callback();
    }
});


callback = function(){
    alert('you have clicked 10 times within 5 seconds');
}
```

What it does is:

for each click on the page it adds timeout to the `tOuts` array. When 5 seconds have been passed since the click - the element from the array is being removed, so
the count of the elements in the array is the total clicks the user have made in the `5` seconds interval since the last click.

After the count reaches `10` all the timeouts are being cleared and the callback is being executed, so in order to execute the callback again - the user will have to make 10 more clicks.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5TFVD/3/)

Answer (score 8):

Mouse clicks (except those ones which propagation is stopped) are bubbling, so you can just listen live clicks on document.body.

Then, you should keep an array, where you store last 10 clicks timestamps (when length is 10, just remove first one before pushing new one). Check first and last timestamp delta, thats it.

Comment: This is the correct solution, the other ones only work every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var numberOfClicks= [];

$(document).click(function(e){
    if(numberOfClicks.length < 10){
       numberOfClicks.push(new Date().getTime());
    }else{
        var diff = numberOfClicks[numberOfClicks.length -1] - numberOfClicks[0];
        console.log(diff);
        if(diff < 5000){
            //alert("toomany!");
            e.preventDefault();
         }
        numberOfClicks.shift();
        numberOfClicks.push(new Date().getTime());     
        console.log(numberOfClicks);
    }
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WWpqZ/

EDIT - this code doesn't consider the time you spent watching the alert and clicking ok

```
var numberOfClicks= [];
alertTime = 0;
$(document).click(function(){
    if(numberOfClicks.length < 10){
       numberOfClicks.push(new Date().getTime());
    }else{

        var diff = numberOfClicks[numberOfClicks.length -1] - numberOfClicks[0] - alertTime;

        if(diff < 5000){
            var beforeAlert = new Date().getTime();
            alert("toomany!");
            var afterAlert = new Date().getTime();
            alertTime = afterAlert - beforeAlert;
         }
        numberOfClicks.shift();
        numberOfClicks.push(new Date().getTime());     

    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WWpqZ/1/

Comment: What if you've clicked 15 times and the alert pops up you wait 1000 seconds (js pauses the execution) and then you press `OK` and then you click again ?

Comment: @Teneff the pause is considered as "time spent on the page" since i just use timestamps and check their difference. You could calculate the time the alert is shown by using two more timestamps and then subtract that value from the diff if you want

Comment: @Teneff i updated my answer so that the time spent clicking ok in the alert is not considered as time on the page

Comment: Actualy, I don't want to display alert, I just want to  `event.preventDefault();` for click action.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti, on first example I changed alert() line with `event.preventDefault(); return false;`. But, If I too many click on my jQuery UI Calendar, it stil work on every click and trying to get data :( How can I stop it?

Comment: Note that if the interval is increased the alert will be executed after each click after the alert.

Comment: I do this http://jsfiddle.net/WWpqZ/5/  I want if user clicks too much, I just want to see "STOP" message. But now it prints "Clicked ! STOP !" together. preventDefault() din't work.

Answer (score 1):

what about this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var amountOfClicks = 0;
  window.setInterval("resetClicks()", 5000);


  $('body').click(function(){
     amountOfClicks++;
     if(amountOfClicks > 10){
alert('You clicked more than 10 times the last 5 seconds');
resetClicks();
}
  });

});

function resetClicks(){
  amountOfClicks = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. You just need to call `resetClicks()` after alerting the warning, otherwise any further clicks will get the warning too.

Comment: Edited the code to your comment :)
Thanks, forgot to put it in

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript:

```js
// Click listener
document.addEventListener("click", clickListener, false);
var counting = 0,
    clicks = 1;
function clickListener(e) {
    // Count the number of clicks
    clicks++;
    if (!counting) {
        counting = 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (clicks > 9) {
                alert('Multiple clicks! ('+clicks+')');
            }
            counting = 0;
            clicks = 0;
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```